# How to find asymptotic sum of highly oscillatory series?

Tags: summation, asymptotics, divergent-series

I have a sum given by,

$$(1) \quad | S_w=\sum_{n=1}^{w} 3^{n/2} \cdot \sin(3^n \cdot t) |$$

How do I find the value of $(1)$ asymptotically?

I can guess, using knowledge about the fractal dimension of weierstrass functions to get,

$$(2) \quad S_w \sim w^{1/2}$$

How do I do I find the sum without resorting to knowledge about the fractal dimension of tangentially related objects?

Also, I wish to have information about how to find asymptotic forms for other highly oscillatory series. Any references or methods would help.

Comment: Is $t$ arbitrary? Numerically it doesn't look like $S_w \sim w^{1/2}$, rather it seems like $S_w = \Theta(3^{w/2})$. Further it looks like $3^{-w/2} S_w$ oscillates pretty chaotically (e.g. for $t=1$).

Comment: @AntonioVargas Yes, although for simplification taking $t=0$ helps. Also, idk about the sum. I just used a definition of the fractal dimension, perhaps improperly, to get a guess.